# How to define a constexpr variable

Tags: c++11, constexpr

I want to use a simple compile time constant for example like this:

```
double foo(double x) { return x + kConstDouble; }
```

Now I see at least the following ways to define that constant

```
namespace { static constexpr double kConstDouble = 5.0; }
namespace { constexpr double kConstDouble = 5.0; }
static constexpr double kConstDouble = 5.0;
constexpr double kConstDouble = 5.0;
```

Which is the right way to go? Is there a difference when `kConstDouble` is defined in a header vs a source file?

Comment: All four are ok and you might also `#define kConstDouble 5.0`

Answer (score 0):

Using static or an anonymous namespace will cause the variable to have internal linkage; it will only be visible within the same translation unit. So if you use one of these within a .cpp file, you won't be able to use the variable anywhere else. This would be done typically if the constant is an implementation detail of that unit of code. If you want to expose it to other translation units, you'll need to put it in a header file. The typical way to do that would be to declare it static (or put it in anonymous namespace), since it is a trivial and constant variable. The other approach would be to declare it extern in the header, and define it in the .cpp to get a truly global variable (as opposed top one where actually every tu has its own copy).

Between static and anonymous namespace; well you don't need both first of all. They both do the same thing AFAIK. But I think it is more idiomatic at this point to use anonymous namespaces in cpp files, as they can be used to also give functions, classes, etc internal linkage. On the other hand, when you want to use it for making a variable globally available, it's more common to use static; I never use anonymous namespaces in header files as I find it misleading.